# tcpdf page number getting 0

Tags: php, tcpdf

In tcpdf i am trying to add some page, and getting `Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0`, can not find a way to solve.

here is my code:

```
require_once('../tcpdf.php');
// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
//Page header
public function Test( $ae ) {
    if( !isset($this->xywalter) ) {
        $this->xywalter = array();
    }
    $this->xywalter[] = array($this->GetX(), $this->GetY());
}
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, 'A1', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set Rotate
$params = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(90));

// other configs
$pdf->setOpenCell(0);
$pdf->SetCellPadding(0);
$pdf->setCellHeightRatio(1.25);

// create some HTML content
$html = '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<thead>
<tr bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
<th rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center">ATIVIDADES E PROCESSOS</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center" valign="bottom">ASPECTOS</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center">IMPACTOS</th>
<th colspan="3" width="6%" align="center">MEIO</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th colspan="9" width="18%" align="center">CLASSIFICA&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center">PROGRAMA</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center">SUBPROGRAMA</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center">A&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES DE CONTROLE, MEDIDAS MITIGADORAS, COMPENSAT&Oacute;RIAS E POTENCIALIZADORAS</th>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
<th align="center" height="200"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
<td colspan="20" align="center">Planejamento</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td rowspan="3" width="15%" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Divulga&ccedil;&atilde;o do empreendimento</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%" align="left">Oferta de empregos diretos e indiretos</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%" align="left">Atra&ccedil;&atilde;o de popula&ccedil;&atilde;o para as comunidades do entorno</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center"></td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center"></td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">X</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center">AII</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">-</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">Ind</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">T</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">Mp</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">Po</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">D</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">R</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">M</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">M</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center">M</td>
<td width="10%">Programa de Apoio ao Desenvolvimento Socioeconomico da Regi&atilde;o</td>
<td width="10%">Subprograma de Apoio ao Desenvolvimento Habitacional</td>
<td width="15%">Coibir ocupa&ccedil;&atilde;o indevida de &aacute;reas inadequadas</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td>Programa de Comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o Social</td>
<td> -</td>
<td>A&ccedil;&otilde;es de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o sobre o empreendimento e quest&otilde;es ambientais</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td align="left">Gera&ccedil;&atilde;o de expectativas na popula&ccedil;&atilde;o</td>
<td align="left">Gera&ccedil;&atilde;o de expectativas junto a popula&ccedil;&atilde;o</td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center">X</td>
<td align="center">AII</td>
<td align="center">-</td>
<td align="center">Dir</td>
<td align="center">T</td>
<td align="center">Im</td>
<td align="center">Co</td>
<td align="center">L</td>
<td align="center">R</td>
<td align="center">P</td>
<td align="center">P</td>
<td align="center">B</td>
<td>Programa de Comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o Social</td>
<td> -</td>
<td>A&ccedil;&otilde;es de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o sobre o empreendimento e questoes ambientais</td>
</tr>
</table>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// array with names of columns
$arr_nomes = array(
array("ABRANGÃŠNCIA", 8, 59), // array(name, new X, new Y);
array("SIGNIFICÃ‚NCIA", 8, 59),
array("FÃSICO", 4, 52),
array("BIÃ“TICO", 4, 52),
array("SOCIOECONÃ”MICO", 4, 52),
array("NATUREZA", 4, 52),
array("ORIGEM", 4, 52),
array("DURAÃ‡ÃƒO", 4, 52),
array("OCORRÃŠNCIA / TEMPORALIDADE", 4, 52),
array("FREQUÃŠNCIA", 4, 52),
array("ESPACIALIZAÃ‡ÃƒO", 4, 52),
array("REVERSIBILIDADE", 4, 52),
array("MAGNITUDE", 4, 52),
array("RELEVÃ‚NCIA", 4, 52)
);

// num of pages
$ttPages = $pdf->getNumPages();
for($i=1; $i<=$ttPages; $i++) {
// set page
$pdf->setPage($i);
// all columns of current page
foreach( $arr_nomes as $num => $arrCols ) {
    $x = $pdf->xywalter[$num][0] + $arrCols[1]; // new X
    $y = $pdf->xywalter[$num][1] + $arrCols[2]; // new Y
    $n = $arrCols[0]; // column name
    // transforme Rotate
    $pdf->StartTransform();
    // Rotate 90 degrees counter-clockwise
    $pdf->Rotate(90, $x, $y);
    $pdf->Text($x, $y, $n);
    // Stop Transformation
    $pdf->StopTransform();
}
}

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

i think `$pdf->getNumPages();` is returning `0` but in `for` loop i have added `$i=1; $i<=$ttPages; $i++`.
here is the errors i have got,
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17126

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17491

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17491

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17941

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18239

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17126

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17491

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17491

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17941

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18239

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17491

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17941

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18239

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17491

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17126

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\software\html\own\office\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17491
TCPDF ERROR: Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0
  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

`$pdf->AddPage('P','A4');` before `$html`